# confuse SQL Server datatype decimal over 15 digit after comma

Tags: sql-server, decimal, numeric

I have table with structure as follow :

```
Table1 (
   id int NULL,
   description varchar(50) null,
   rate decimal(18,15) NULL
)
```

and when I test insert data into the table problem value like this :

```
insert into Table1 (id, description, rate)
values (1, 'My Room Upstair',  38397.0893181818)
```

and the error like this :

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
> converting numeric to data type numeric.

But when I use Float data type the data inserted successful. But the rate value change to different value.

need advice please...

solution of decimal data type problem

Comment: `decimal(18,15)` means you have 3 digits before the decimal place. Your value `38397.0893181818` is clearly exceeded that

Comment: What different value in float? You can change float data to real data using str() or cast().
```STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )  ```

Comment: sorry @Squirrel, can you more specific, what should I declare for inserting 38397.0893181818 into decimal data type?

Comment: Use the number of decimal places you wish to support i.e. less than 15. And/or increase 18 to a higher value. And definitely do not use float. It's not the correct data type for money. Please do read the documentation for the decimal data type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the **decimal** data type correctly.

The data type is defined like this `decimal(a, b)`.

**a** is used to specify the amount of digits in the value. The default value is 18, but you can choose whatever number between 1, which is the minimum and 38, which is the maximum.

**b** is used for the amount of digits after the decimal point. The default value is 0 but you can specify choosing between the minimum and maximum, which are the same 1 and 38. **b** can only be specified if **a** is also specified. It needs to be equal or less than **a**.

In your example **decimal(18,15)**, you can insert a number that is 18 digits long, 3 before and 15 after the decimal point. **38397.0893181818** has 5 digits before the decimal point, which is why you get the error. So if you need to add 38397.0893181818, you need decimal(15,10), since the number has 15 digits, 10 of which are after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the decimal(a,b) parameters work according to what you need, a defines the number of total digits and b defines the number of digits of that total that will go after the decimal point.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).